# Easiest strategy for a two-master repo

Tags: git

I have the following situation:

- third-party github repo
- local clone of the third-party repo
- personal remote, to push changes in the local clone

The personal remote is *not* in github.

I want to be able to do three things:

1. make changes in a branch (let's call it `testing`) to the local repo
2. pull from the original remote to the master branch
3. push the `testing` branch to my personal remote (for backup)

I am not sure how to add the personal remote to my local clone, so that the original remote is still functional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git remote add personal git://url.to.your.personal.repository` will let you add your remote. You can push your testing branch to it with `git push personal testing`. Your original remote should remain unaffected. The man pages for `git remote`, `git push`, and other commands should help you figure out other things you might want to do with your remotes. Usually it boils down to specifying which remote you want to perform an action on if no default has been chosen, or if you want to operate on a remote other than the default.